# SFML 2.3 Codeblocks Crash

Tags: c++, crash, codeblocks, sfml

I just set up SFML 2.3 on CodeBlocks 13.12 but when I try to build&run this code :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Blabla");
    while(window.isOpen()){
        sf::Event e;
        while(window.pollEvent(e)){
            if(e.type==sf::Event::Closed){
                window.close();
            }
        }
        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It crashes. I linked these "audio graphics main network system window" in linker setting.
Can someone help me?

Comment: what does the compiler says?

Comment: it compiles without problem, but when I run it, it crashes

Comment: It is important to link to the libraries that match the configuration: "sfml-xxx-d" for Debug, and "sfml-xxx" for Release. A bad mix may result in crashes. did you do this?

Comment: yes i did link libsfml-xxxx-d.a for Debug and libsfml-xxxx.a for Release.
Should I recompile SFML myself with CMake ?

Comment: post the error message. There is no magic gnome who transmits your error codes across the universe.

Comment: Look http://imgur.com/hX75T1p

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve it, I recompiled SFML using mingw32-make (I added .../codeblocks/mingw/bin to path variables) then I placed dll generated by the compilation into the project folder. (here is how you build sfml : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1zN_QRSwxw&ab_channel=AlexThorne
I hope I helped people who had the same issue
(Sorry for my english)